# Limit memory usage while writing parquet files concurrently with arrow(cpp)?

Tags: c++, parquet, apache-arrow

I'm working on extract data from database and write to parquet files with arrow(c++, version 8.0), and here is my code:

```cpp
  auto schema = BuildParquetSchema(...);
  std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::FileOutputStream> outfile;
  // parquet::WriterProperties::Builder builder;
  PARQUET_ASSIGN_OR_THROW(outfile,
                          arrow::io::FileOutputStream::Open(path.string()));
  // using dafault writer properties
  parquet::StreamWriter os{parquet::ParquetFileWriter::Open(outfile, schema)};
  os.SetMaxRowGroupSize(1000);
  // then write data
  ...
```

This codes are wrppped in a function called `WriteFile()`, and I create 400 tasks(by calling this function) using `std::async` to accelerate the whole process, then I found the program used too much memory(80% of 128GB in 8 mins), and caused OOM.

So the question is: how could I set up the parquet::WriterProperties to reduce the memory usage, (like 40GB) and do not cause OMM in a long term?